# SQLite does not see PrimaryKey attribute

Tags: sqlite, windows-runtime, primary-key

I have a problem in updating and inserting data to local sqlite database. Here's code:

```
public class Klient : INotifyPropertyChanged, IEquatable<Klient>
 {
    [SQLite.PrimaryKey, SQLite.AutoIncrement]
    public int id { get; set; }
```

Basing on this class database has been created through sqlite-net. Here's a screenshot from  SQLite database Browser
[image: ss]

The error says that I cannot update or insert, because there is no PK. As I looked up in locals:
IsPK is false
Attributes are null,
but Custom Attributes are as should be: PrimaryKey, Autoincrement.
Never had such problem, I've been using sqlite for six months now. Any suggestions please?
I'm working on Windows 8.1 app, with WIN RT, .NET 4.5.1, VS 2013 Ultimate.

The class is in second project, class library. Error invokes when working with project having reference to class library.

```
'(map.Columns[0].ColumnType).GenericParameterAttributes' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' 
+   {"Method may only be called on a Type for which Type.IsGenericParameter is true."}
```

Comment: did this external reference has apply copy always? Did you have tryed to clean and then rebuild solution?

Comment: "copy local" is true. tried rebuilding - no result. i found some exception, please see question.

Comment: do u use some reflection? If not it's seems to be bug in SQLite library. which version do you use exactly?

Comment: Latest, I guess, (reinstalled today), it's SQLite for Windows Runtime (Windows 8.1) 3.8.2.0.
What is strange insertions invoked (in my opinion) at the same level, from the same project, worked and I filled the database with example data of the same type and no 'no PK' error was raised.
Reflection? I don't think so, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Seems like GetMapping method in Update (line 1157 SQLite.cs) does not find a PK, but GetMapping in Insert (some lines above 1157) does.

Comment: Reflection is used by sqlite-net while mapping type properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I accidentally added sqlite.cs file to to main project (not library) which was also a part of .dll imported from another project - class library. So do not ignore green underlines which IDE provides you with, especially if it's class conflict ;)
Thank you @harry180!